# Can i prevent a non-root user using logger to make fake entries (e.g. sshd) in the syslog?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

i just played with logger an non-root user, but it looks like everyone is able to create fake entries in the syslog using the "-t" parameter.

Is this expected to work this way?
I could flood the log or hide some actions below a flood of different fake entries - not good in means of system security.

Can i prevent it?
=> logger is part of the package util-linux-systemd (previous util-linux) and cannot be uninstalled easily, secondly it is executable for everyone on the machine by default.

used System: different SuSE Linux (SLE 10, 11, 15)

command line:

```
justin@garfield:~ > logger -t sshd[986]: Accepted publickey from 127.0.0.19.8 port 65537 sha2: RSA 2e:45:25:54:6o:34:3a:z3:55:07:04 (just a fake)"
justin@garfield:~ > su -l
Password:
root@garfield:~ > tail -n 2 /var/log/messages
Oct 27 13:35:45 garfield sshd[986]: Accepted publickey from 127.0.0.19.8 port 65537 sha2: RSA 2e:45:25:54:6o:34:3a:z3:55:07:04 (just a fake)
Oct 27 13:36:21 garfield su: (to root) justin on /dev/pts/0
```

Note: I just used impossible values (IP, publickey) to make it a clear to be a fake entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is expected to work this way, sometimes it is quite useful to post log messages from a script. It was certainly not intended for users to pollute the system logs. The solution in my opinion is having a well configured logging system, which will prevent users from polluting the logs, or faking system messages, allowing you to identify users who are in the habit of doing so.

I use `rsyslogd`, so I'm using that for examples.

First of all, you need to configure `rsyslogd` to store certain variables from the socket it opens:

```
module (load="imuxsock"
    SysSock.Annotate="on"
    SysSock.ParseTrusted="on"
)
```

With this, you can access the following variables:

- `pid`: the PID of the logging process.
- `uid` and `gid`: the UID and GID the logging process runs as.
- `appname`: the name of the logging process
- `cmd`: the full command line of the logging process

In the case of `logger`, `pid` will be the PID of `systemd-journald`, and `appname` will always be `systemd-journal`.
With these, you can do a few things:

#### Simply log these

You can use a template which includes these variables, so you can see if there is a discrepancy between the message and the obtained parameters. In a template, you can access these variables like `%$!pid%`. So for example, of you use a template like this:

```
$template SomeLogFormat,"%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% <%pri-text%> %syslogtag%%msg% (logged by pid=%$!pid% running as %$!uid%)\n"

daemon.* /var/log/daemon.log;SomeLogFormat
```

will yield the following entry:

```
2021-10-27T18:27:54.638759+02:00 <daemon.info> sshd[986]: Accepted publickey from 127.0.0.19.8 port 65537 sha2: RSA 2e:45:25:54:6o:34:3a:z3:55:07:04 (just a fake) (logged by pid=540 running as 1000)
```

From it, you can see if the message is legit, and if not, you get the UID of the user who is in a funny mood. Note that instead of supplying the parameters one by one, you can use the `%$!%` template, which will log the above values in JSON format.

#### Reroute user logs

You can place logs written by users to a separate file (perhaps on a separate file system, so that users can't fill the root filesystem). You can reroute all logs originating from users with the following config:

```
if $!uid > 999 then /opt/log/user.log;SomeLogFormat
& stop
```

The usage of the template (the `;SomeLogFormat` part) is optional. This way, everything originating from anything with an UID of 1000+ will be written to `/opt/log/user.log`. You can even separate the user logs by UID like this:

```
$template userLogFile,"/opt/log/userlog_%$!uid%.log"

if $!uid > 999 then ?userLogFile;SomeLogFormat
& stop
```

This way, every user will have their own `userlog_xxxx.log` file.